# Format casing of names when first letter is repeated

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

I have a function which takes an array of names and returns a new array with each name's first letter transformed to uppercase (and the remaining letters lowercase).

```
function capMe(arr) {
  let newArr = [];
  arr.forEach(function(name) {
    name = name.replace(name[0], name[0].toUpperCase());
    for(let i = 1; i < name.length; i++) {
        name = name.replace(name[i], name[i].toLowerCase());
    }
    newArr.push(name);
});
return newArr;
}
```

This works for the vast majority of the time. For example, if I call the function like this:

```
console.log(capMe(['jACKSON', 'pAM', 'wiLliAm']));
```

I will receive the desired output of `> Array ["Jackson", "Pam", "William"]`.

However, there is one case in which this function does not work. If I call the function with a name which has the first letter repeated, every letter will be lowercase except for the second occurrence of the letter.

For example, If I add `gEORGANN` to the previous example, I will receive this output:

`> Array ["georGann", "Jackson", "Pam", "William"]`

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current logic is not doing what you think it is.  Consider the following line which appears in the loop over each name:

```
name = name.replace(name[i], name[i].toLowerCase());
```

This is replacing the *first* character only which is equal to `name[i]` with the lowercase version of that letter.  Here is how this is throwing off your logic with the input `gEORGANN`.  First, you *uppercase* the first `g`, to get `GEORGANN`.  Then, when the loop hits the fourth position, which is a capital `G`, it replaces the *first* `G` with a lowercase `g`.  This leaves us with `gEORGANN`, but it is not what you intend.  The reason for this is that `replace` just hits the first occurrence.

You *might* be able to remedy this by doing a replace all instead of a replace.  But why not just take the first character in uppercase concatenated with the remainder of the string in lowercase:

```js
arr = ['georGann', 'jACKSON', 'pAM', 'wiLliAm'];
newArr = [];
arr.forEach(function(name) {
    newName = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1).toLowerCase()
    newArr.push(newName);
});
console.log(arr);
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: OP might want to consider adding a string split by " " or "-", for people with multiple or strange first names.

Comment: "This is replacing all characters which are equal to name[i]" — No, there is no `g` flag, it is replacing the **first**.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen — Don't make assumptions about where downvotes come from.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
const capMe = (arr = []) => {
  return arr.map((name) => {
    const [first, ...rest] = name;
    return `${first.toUpperCase()}${rest.join('').toLowerCase()}`;
  });
}

console.log(capMe(['foo', 'foZBaz']));
```

Comment: NMD (= not my downvote), but maybe you should also try to explain why the OP's current approach is failing.

Comment: True. I was a bit too hasty with this. But not worth of a downvote, though.

Comment: I agree +1.  Working code usually does not merit a downvote +1.

Answer (score -1):

Your coding logic is fine. The problem is the order of operations. Please see below;

```js
function capMe(arr) {
    let newArr = [];
    arr.forEach(function(name) {
      name = name.toLowerCase();
      name = name.replace(name[0], name[0].toUpperCase());
      newArr.push(name);
    });
   return newArr;
}
console.log(capMe(['gEORGANN', 'pAM', 'wiLliAm', 'AA']));
```

Comment: This may coincidentally fix the OP's issue, but it might not be the best way to go about doing this.

Comment: This wouldn't work if there were two identical uppercase characters in the input.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen correct. I am pointing out that his logic is correct for a reason. Its not the best way of doing yes. But this answer is more inline with his/her train of thought

Comment: Read Quentin's comment above :-)